# Find the probability mass function of X.

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be the number of times a person falls down a particular set of stairs. The probability that he falls at least once out of ten times is equal to 0.943686.

So first I want to find P(0).

$P(0) = 1 - P(X \geq 1) = 0.056314$

Now I want to find $p$, the chance of the person falling down the stairs.

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0)$

$0.943686 = 1 - (1 - p)^{10}$

$p = 0.25$

Now I'm not sure how to get the PMF. I've tried two solutions.

The first solution, I've tried to calculate $P(1) = (\frac{1}{4})^1 \cdot (\frac{3}{4})^9$, $P(2) = (\frac{1}{4})^2 \cdot (\frac{3}{4})^8$, etc.

The second solution, I've tried using $P(x) = p^x(1 - p)^{1-x}$.

But with both solutions, they do not add up to 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I've been using the wrong formula the whole time. I should've been using $P(x) = {n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$.